# How does the process of deleteMany/remove work in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How does the process of deleteMany/remove work? Does it find all the documents which're matching the condition, store in memory and delete orderly?

```
db.collection.deleteMany({condition})
db.collection.remove({condition})
```

Comment: What is the point of storing in memory? No document data is needed to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Its work according to condition you specifying. It delete one or more document if exists.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but I want to know how actually mongodb process delete command, not the result as you said

Answer (score 0):

Barring an answer from a server engineer more familiar with the situation, I would expect that deletion works as follows:

1. A find query is executed with the provided conditions.
2. As each document is found by the query, it is removed.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#cursor-snapshot specifies that a cursor may return a document more than once. This doesn't meaningfully affect deletes since deleting a document that is already deleted is a no-op.

When the delete is executed outside of a transaction, I would expect that:

- A document that is concurrently modified by another query, that matches the deletion conditions, may end up not being deleted if it ends up being physically overwritten & moved by the database.
- If there are documents being inserted concurrently with the deletion that match the deletion condition, some, all or none of them may be deleted by the deletion query.

I would hope that in a transaction the first of these scenarios wouldn't be possible and in the second scenario either all newly inserted documents would be removed or none will, but I wouldn't claim this without testing since I don't see such statements in published documentation.